# How to update a label in a specific UITableViewCell without reloading all UITableView data?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, tableview

I am trying to refresh the label in a UITableViewCell without having to refresh the entire table. This is for making a timer-app, where I will be refreshing the labels in the UITableView every second (when it's counting down).

[Link to a simulator screenshot of the table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgYv2.png)

In the past, I've tried reloading the data of the entire UITableView five times every second, but this results in sliding to delete being very inconsistent and hard to perform. I haven't succeeded in updating individual rows yet, so I don't know if that's a possible solution.

I couldn't find any similar question, but if you know that it's been asked before, please redirect me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: It's perfectly fine to reach right into the cells and change their labels directly as long as you stay consistent with the data, i.e. you also change the data model. You don't have to set the data and call reload.

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for! That's what I have problems with though. Do you know how to access to labels?

Comment: you can reload the particular row cell instead.

Comment: @DivyaS I can't seem to make that work. I have a separate swift document that tells the view controller when to update the tableview. I've tried using protocols and delegates, but with no success. I actually made a post describing that problem as well

Comment: Are you able to get index path of the cell?

Comment: If you want to reload cells alone then you can reload specific cells using this code
`tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)`

Comment: Well, you've shown zero code in _this_ question so I can't help. However, you can ask the table view for all currently visible cells and their index paths so you should easily be able to manipulate the cells however you like.

Comment: @matt It's just a basic table view. Nothing fancy. Which parts of the code would you need to see to know how it could be done. I'm currently trying to set a timer with refreshing of the label, inside of the class I have for my table view cell. It feels like a pretty odd solution though.

Comment: @DivyaS Not at the moment. I have had some problems with that. My first post was about that. Got 0 response though. The question was too specific I believe.

Comment: just change the label withing the cell instead of reloading the table or reloading the cell. eg. let cell = cellforRowAtIndexPath(), cell.label.text = "time" etc. WIth way you can delete the cell with the swipe

Comment: @RJE Good idea! I'll try it out, well, when I'm able to find the row of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can find out  index of the respective label then  you can easily  get the cell and access the label and do what ever you want to do

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 2, section: 0)
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? YourTableViewCell {
        cell.YourLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.green // write as per your requirement
    }
```

Comment: This causes unexpected behavior when the user scrolls.

Comment: You have to call this function whenever it is required ,scrolling won't affect this function .

Comment: This may work... I'm just having some trouble with finding the row. The timer object (object of my timer class that contains everything to make the timer works) used protocols and delegates to get the info of the timer object (like the timer's ID). Inside the delegate function in my view controller though, I can't access the array that stores all the timer objects (the data source of the table view). Well, it returns '[]' when I know that it contains one item.

Comment: Scrolling won't affect the function but it will affect the appearance of the cell. Consider that cells are reused.

Comment: @Shakti Ok I think I got it to work now! Was able to find the row in a decent way. Thanks a lot! Accepting this answer now.

Answer (score 6):

The most efficient way in Swift is a callback closure. It causes much less overhead than protocol/delegate or notification.

- Run the timers in the data model.
- In the model declare a callback property

  ```
  var updateLabel : ((String) -> Void)?
  ```

  and call it when the timer fires

  ```
  @objc func timerDidFire(_ sender: Timer) {
      updateLabel?("New Value") // replace "New Value" with the actual value
  }
  ```
- In `cellForRowAt` assign a closure to the `updateLabel` property to update the label

  ```
  let model = datasourceArray[indexPath.row]
  model.updateLabel = { value in
      cell.textLabel.text = value
  }
  ```
- In `tableView:didEndDisplaying:forRowAt:` remove the closure

  ```
  let model = datasourceArray[indexPath.row]
  model.updateLabel = nil
  ```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like a great way to do it. May change this to the accepted answer once I manage to fully wrap my head around the code haha